What's an appropriate fluid simulation configuration for a 10,000 kilometre body of water?
I want to model a geological disaster which will disrupt an ocean 10,000 kilometres across, and up to 2,000m deep. (Yes, it needs to be simulated all the way to the bottom.)
I know the 3d data involved would be ludicrous, so outputting a heightmap (8 bits per square metre) once per X frames would be fine.
It's okay to pretend the Earth is flat.
The only objects in the scene are water and the earth's solid (but changing) crust.
The timescale of the simulated event is several days.
I don't need this to produce final render quality data, just give me something physically plausible (accurate-ish) which I can process into something else later on.
Ideally, it would produce "reasonable" results within a few days using my desktop computer at home.
I don't mind coarse output. Something like a 1-metre resolution would be okay, or even lower, like maybe 10m, as long as this doesn't lead to silly physics.
I don't know how suitable the off-the-shelf product is for this. Perhaps there would be issues at certain resolutions, or time step considerations, or something.
I don't know if Blender is suitable for such a task or whether I should use something else entirely
What configuration/settings would be appropriate?

I see multiple issues. 1) We'd need to know what kind of event (small waves VS big water splash 2) A fluid simulation with a 10'000km domain and resolution of 1 or 10m will never happen 3) Simulating 1m waves when looking at the entire domain, it would be too small to be seen 4) Blender isn't supposed to give realistic result, for example FLIP fluid simulations only simulate surface of liquids 5) 99,99% of your water body won't be moving (if small waves), why would you want to simulate unmoving water ?
I would recommend taking a look at other tools, such as SPH simulations.

Also 6) You are talking about height maps, but these are used for 2D objects (such as surface of water). You are saying you want to simulate a 3D body of water, so height maps won't cut it.

I do not know about your hardware, but some people's PCs already struggle with domain resolution divisions of 200 or 500... when you want 10 m resolution in a domain with a side length of 10,000 km, this would mean you have to set the resolution divisions to 1,000,000 (1 million!) Even if Blender were capable of simulating this theoretically (which I doubt), for sure your hardware will get a performance problem...
